# MS Office Repair Issue

Tags: microsoft-office

I am really desperate trying to fix microsoft office.

I received message that office is broken and won't start, after that I tried to repair (Quick and Online) but didn't help.

Tried to uninstall and was unable to uninstall. Used "Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant" and finally uninstalled it.

I have deleted all folders related to Office and cleaned registry.

Restarted multiple times.

Tried to install but again without luck.

"Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant" is unable to install office too.

I tried office 2013, 2016 and 2019. Couldn't install but 2010 installed without issue.

Also checked comp for viruses...

Don't know what else to try.

Comment: You will have to uninstall everything related to Office. All versions. Manually remove the folders in Program Files, then reboot, and then try to install again.

Comment: You have to do it specifically in that order. I could not make that up from your post, so I wanted to be clear. Also, turning the pc off and then on is not the same as reboot and thus will not work. you really have to reboot.

Comment: You are going to need to provide us more information.

Comment: Office installations are streamed, that error code is an indication you are unable to download the required data.  This is a network configuration issue.  Vital information should be contained in the question body.  Unnecessary commentary will be flagged as "no longer needed".

Comment: You should use the tool on [Uninstall Office automatically](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027149/how-to-uninstall-office-automatically) to cleanup your existing installations.  Unnecessary commentary containing information that should be in the question body will be flagged and deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108628/discussion-between-ramhound-and-arnes).

Comment: If the Office uninstall tool doesn't completely uninstall Office from your PC, you can try to [manually uninstall Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b).

Comment: At the end, I can uninstall Office, with the tool or manually but installation does not work. I have manually removed ALL folders related to Office and registry keys which I found but installation not working and setup repair not working either. :(